# python logging: Custom Python LogRecord Throwing an error

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to use the python logging module to create a custom log file that records other information like host name and adds it to my DB. Below are the classes I created to do this, and the Handler part was working just fine, but now that I added a custom `LogRecord` class, it throws this error:

```
/src/lib/__init__.py", line 31, in __init__
logging.LogRecord.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
exceptions.TypeError: __init__() takes at most 9 arguments (10 given)
```

And here is how I execute it

```
logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)

log = logging.getLogger('testing')
log.addHandler(MyLogHandler())
d = {'host': '192.168.0.1'}
log.warn('Hi', d)
```

And here are the classes. It obviously has to do with the *args, **kwargs, but when I look at it, the *args is empty, and **kwargs only contains the `d` variable specified above. I don't understand the problem.

```
class MyLogRecord(logging.LogRecord):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.LogRecord.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) //THIS IS THE LINE IT DIES ON
        self.host = 'localhost'

class MyLogFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def __init__(self, fmt, datefmt=None, host=None):
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, fmt, datefmt)
        self.host = host

    def format(self, record):
        return logging.Formatter.format(record)

class MyLogger(logging.getLoggerClass()):
    def makeRecord(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return MyLogRecord(*args, **kwargs)

class MyLogHandler(logging.Handler): # Inherit from logging.Handler
    def __init__(self):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        # Our custom argument
        self.mongo = MongoLogger()

    def setupCustomLogger(self, name, this_host):
        formatter = MyLogFormatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - %(message)s - %(host)s')

        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        return logger

    def emit(self, record):
        # record.message is the log message
        self.mongo.log(record)


class MongoLogger(object):

'''Logs messages to a MongoDB fh_admin log collection.'''
def log(self, message):
    #@todo write log to DB
    print message
```

Comment: You've not provided enough code to reproduce the problem.  Even after removing the references to the classes that you haven't included (FirehoseLogRecord, MongoLogger) I cannot reproduce this error you're describing

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question. It shouldn't have been FirehoseLogRecord, it should have been MyLogRecord, which is what is causing the problem.

Comment: See, it dies on superclass init. Does plain `logging.LogRecord.__init__` die on the _same argument list_?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong; you are calling the constructor with too many arguments.  To see what I mean, take a look at how log-records are ordinarily constructed in the default implementation of `makeRecord`:

```
def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None):
    """
    A factory method which can be overridden in subclasses to create
    specialized LogRecords.
    """
    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
    if extra is not None:
        for key in extra:
            if (key in ["message", "asctime"]) or (key in rv.__dict__):
                raise KeyError("Attempt to overwrite %r in LogRecord" % key)
            rv.__dict__[key] = extra[key]
    return rv
```

Notice how makeRecord takes an `extra` param that it doesn't pass directly to `LogRecord`?  You, on the other hand, are passing that directly to `LogRecord.__init__`, which is causing the error.

From here, you've got two options; you could provide a more complete implementation of `makeRecord`, or you could try using the `LoggerAdapter` class which should help you achieve the same goal with less code.

Here's an example:

```
# Common log info to be added to all logs reported with `log_adapter`
context = {'host': 'localhost'}

log = logging.getLogger('testing')
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
d = {'host': '192.168.0.1'}

log_adapter = logging.LoggerAdapter(log, context)
log_adapter.warning('Hi', d)
```

If you need to calculate the value of 'host' (for example) each time something is logged, you could make `context` an instance of a class that looks like a dictionary.  Like so:

```
class LogContext(object):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'host':
            return 'localhost'
        raise KeyError(key)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(['host'])

log_adapter = logging.LoggerAdapter(log, LogContext())
log_adapter.warning('Hi', d)
```

One thing to note about `LoggingAdapter`, it apparently doesn't define all of the handy shortcut functions as the ordinary Logger class.  That's why I've called the `warning` method instead of `warn` as you did above.

More info on `LoggingAdapter` and adding context to your logs can be found in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-loggeradapters-to-impart-contextual-information).

NOTE - I didn't include `MyLogHandler`, `MyLogFormatter`, or `MongoLogger` in my examples as they were not relevant to the issue/error.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, I noticed after I went back to where I got info from to reconstruct this for myself, the code was posted 5 years ago. A bit has probably changed since then. :) http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474089-extending-the-logging-module/ I think I should be able to piece all this together to write my custom logs to the DB. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: The LoggingAdapter looks like the way to go, plus I spent so much time messing around with logs, I think it all blurred together, much clearer now!

Comment: I am guessing the LoggerAdapter doesn't have a logging.getLogger('testing') to make it easy to find this throughout the application?

Comment: @Hallik Not that I'm aware of, but you could create a simple function that does something similar ex: `def getLogAdapter(name): context = {}; logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger(name), context)`.  Or you just instantiate this adapter in some module then import it wherever you need to use it, or (depending on hour your app is structured, just pass it around.

Comment: Excellent point. I am going to play with that, and using a `Filter` as well. Thanks!

Comment: [The only bug I've ever opened against python](https://bugs.python.org/issue19455) pertains to exactly this.